# Android: TitleBar icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

ActionBar app icon is not showing. It didn't occur before, but after updating Android studio app icon is not showing. I have set in Manifest android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" for app and for activity and it still doesn't show

Comment: Are you sure that your ic_launcher.png file is present on disk, in the drawable-XXXX folder ?

Comment: If you switched destination API level to 21, icon will not be shown, see Android Material design guidelines.

Comment: Yeah, it is in the /res folder of my project.

Comment: It is set to API level 21. Which api level should i set ?

Comment: Set 19 for older "Holo" design.

Comment: Now i have some gradle build errors.
Error:(50, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.

Comment: Some values xml isn't working

Comment: Check manifest and app themes, do not use "Material" themes, switch to adequate Holo themes.

Comment: It is set to Holo.Light theme. This is what i get
C:\Users\joca\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\values-v11\values.xml and 
C:\Users\joca\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\values-v14\values.xml

Comment: OK, try to change appcompat-v7 to previous version v20 in your gradle.build: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0

Comment: You are a God among programmers :D. That was the problem :).